# Backbone - Get Router parameter and reload same route

Tags: backbone.js, routes

I have a table and I'm deleting a row. When I delete this row, I want to reload the current Backbone route, but few things to take in count:

e.g I'm in this route

"oneurl#order-by-name/page-8"

If the table, at that page, has only one record and I delete it, I would like to redirect to #order-by-name/page-7, so I need to get the "page" parameter. If there are still records, I want to "reload" the same route (to add next page's row if there are). It seems is not possible (https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1214).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the issue you link (mainly jashkenas's comment "`trigger: true` is usually a code smell"), you shouldn't really be using routes like that for a javascript application.

What you should be doing instead:

- have somewhere to store the current application's state (e.g. a plain javascript object) which is passed to the function taking care of displaying the views and data you want
- when a row is deleted, modify the application state object (e.g. changing the current page attribute) and call the same function as above, once again passing in the configuration
- update the url with `navigate`only if the fragment should change

In reverse, your router should parse the url fragment to generate a configuration object discussed above, and call the function to render the views (passing in the configuration info).

For more on how to manage routing without using `trigger: true` everywhere, take a look at http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/03/stop-using-backbone-as-if-it-were-a-stateless-web-server/ and the [free preview](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) to [my book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/) (on Marionette, but the same applies to Backbone) which also contains a chapter discussing route handling.